# iOS/Objective-C: library to connect to POP3

Tags: objective-c, ios, pop3

I'd like to connect to IMAP and POP3 servers, for IMAP I'm currently using MailCore. Unfortunately I don't find a suitable POP3-framwork.

I tried with libetpan:

```
    mailpop3 * pop3;
    int r;
    pop3 = mailpop3_new(0, NULL);
    r = mailpop3_ssl_connect(pop3, "pop.gmail.com", 995);
    check_error(r, "connect failed");
```

but I always get a connection refused error; and it's only C, I would prefer Objective-C. Even better would be a library which I could use for both; IMAP and POP3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't used [OCMail](https://github.com/miyabichan/OCMail), but it seems like it's what you're looking for. It claims to support "POP3, IMAP4, SMTP, POPS, IMAPS, SMTPS".

**Edit: Build Error**
Turns out, the solution is actually in the README file.

1. Once you've downloaded the ZIP from Github, open the Xcode project.
2. Build for Profiling (Product Menu > Build For > Profiling (Command-Shift-I)).
3. Open Xcode preferences and go to "Locations"
4. Under Derived Data, next to the Advanced button you'll see a file path (something like `/Users/YourUserName/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData`). There'll be a little arrow next to the path; click the arrow to go to that location in Finder.
5. It'll take you to a folder with all of your Xcode projects. Find the folder whose name starts with OCMail (and has a bunch of gibberish after it).
6. In that folder, find Build > Products > Debug-iphoneos > `libOCMail.a`. That's the library file you'll want to add into *your* Xcode project. Just drag it into your Xcode project and you should be good to go.

I got a bunch of errors building the project. They came from a badly defined `enum` type. Here's a cleaned up file:
http://cl.ly/code/442x2x3X3Y2I

Just download and replace the existing MimeMessage.m file before you build.

Comment: but unfortunately the issue mentioned here https://github.com/miyabichan/OCMail/issues/1 is a real problem for me... couldn't get it to work :/

Comment: okay, I managed to create the .a file; but if I drag it into my test project, I can't import files like e.g. `#import "MailServer.h"` - `file not found`

Comment: You'll have to copy the header files from the original ZIP. Not a big deal, because those files are just declarations; they don't get compiled.

Answer (score 1):

I was working with libetpan in past and I was connecting to pop3 server without problems, so I checked if it still working. I used code from here: https://github.com/dinhviethoa/libetpan/blob/master/tests/pop-sample.c and adjusted it for iOS.

If You use it, You will see a lot of warnings and app will crash after fetching first message, but connecting is working (of course, You need to enter Your email login and password).

I'm not saying  that libetpan is good solution. When I was developing app with mail support I also used mailcore for IMAP and eventually resigned from POP3 support. But if You run from options it could be useful.

```
static void check_error(int r, char * msg)
{
if (r == MAILPOP3_NO_ERROR)
    return;

fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", msg);
exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

-(IBAction)testButtonClick:(id)sender
{
mailpop3 * pop3;
int r;
carray * list;
unsigned int i;

//  if (argc < 3) {
//      fprintf(stderr, "syntax: pop-sample [gmail-email-address] [gmail-     password]\n");
//      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
//  }


mkdir("download", 0700);

pop3 = mailpop3_new(0, NULL);
r = mailpop3_ssl_connect(pop3, "pop.gmail.com", 995);
check_error(r, "connect failed");

r = mailpop3_user(pop3, @"mail login".cString);
check_error(r, "user failed");

r = mailpop3_pass(pop3, @"mail password".cString);
check_error(r, "pass failed");

r = mailpop3_list(pop3, &list);
check_error(r, "list failed");

NSLog(@"carray_count(list_: %d", carray_count(list));

for(i = 0 ; i < carray_count(list) ; i ++) {
    struct mailpop3_msg_info * info;
    char * msg_content;
    size_t msg_size;
    FILE * f;
    char filename[512];

    struct stat stat_info;

    info = (mailpop3_msg_info *) carray_get(list, i);

    if (info->msg_uidl == NULL) {
        continue;
    }

    snprintf(filename, sizeof(filename), "download/%s.eml", info->msg_uidl);
    r = stat(filename, &stat_info);
    if (r == 0) {
        printf("already fetched %u %s\n", info->msg_index, info->msg_uidl);
        continue;
    }

    if(msg_content != NULL)
    NSLog(@"msg_content: %@", [NSString stringWithUTF8String:msg_content]);
    r = mailpop3_retr(pop3, info->msg_index, &msg_content, &msg_size);
    check_error(r, "get failed");

//      f = fopen(filename, "w");
//      fwrite(msg_content, 1, msg_size, f);
//      fclose(f);
//      mailpop3_retr_free(msg_content);

    if (info->msg_uidl != NULL) {
        printf("fetched %u %s\n", info->msg_index, info->msg_uidl);
    }
    else {
        printf("fetched %u\n", info->msg_index);
    }
}

mailpop3_quit(pop3);
mailpop3_free(pop3);

//  exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```